# knockout: nested dependentObservable - not functioning

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, ko.dependentobservable

I am new to Knockout JS. 
I need to bind nested arrays as folows

**Name:** Drop down

**Email:** Selected user's name

**Contact Method Type:** Drop down with Contact Method type from ContactInfo selected

**Contact Value:** Actual value from ContactInfo

I have got Name, email and contact value working. I need to know how to have contact method type value being selected in the drop down and the same need to be bound to contact value.

I get following error
**Error: Unable to get value of the property 'ContactMethodType': object is null or undefined**

```
function LifelineViewModel() {

    this.lifelines = ko.observableArray([{
        Name: "",
        Email: "",
        ContactInfo:
                {
                    ContactMethodType: "",
                    ContactValue: ""
                }
    }]);
    this.selectedLifeline = ko.observable();

    this.contactTypes = ko.observableArray([{Name: ''}]);

    this.selectedContactInfo = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        if (this.selectedLifeline() === undefined) return null;
        return this.selectedLifeline().ContactInfo;
    }, this);

    this.selectedContactMethodType = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        if (this.selectedContactInfo() === undefined) return null;
        return this.selectedContactInfo().ContactMethodType;
    }, this);
```

}

**HTML code**

```
<select data-bind="options: lifelines, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedLifeline"></select>
<p><span data-bind="text: selectedLifeline().Email"></span></p>
<p><span data-bind="text: selectedContactInfo().ContactMethodType + ' ' + selectedContactInfo().ContactValue"></p>
<select data-bind="options: contactTypes, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedContactMethodType"></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies in your second dependentObservable.  By default, dependentObservables are evaluated for the first time when they are created.  In your case, `selectedContactMethodType` will get the current value from `selectedContactInfo` which will be `null`.  This will not match your `undefined` check and then try to read `ContactMethodType` off of `null` which causes the error.

So, you would need to be a bit more careful in how you treat undefined vs. null.

Using the control-flow bindings in [1.3 beta](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/), here is your sample without using dependentObservables to protect against null: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9msqK/